"requires" specialization of a templated class constructor fails to compile
Compiling this code
#include <utility>

class Blob
{
public:
  template<std::unsigned_integral T> Blob(T);

private:
};

template<std::unsigned_integral T> 
requires(sizeof(T) <= 4)
Blob::Blob(T)
{
}

with clang 19.1.0 yields
<source>:13:7: error: out-of-line definition of 'Blob' does not match any declaration in 'Blob'
   13 |     Blob::Blob(T)
      |           ^~~~
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1

While technically true, I wouldn't expect an error since it's a specialization of an existing method. In particular, given that outside of a class this approach seems to work fine, I'm unsure what might be going on here. Perhaps this is due to a bug, or maybe I have a poor understanding of the nuances of requires.

Declaration and definition are diverged by the requires(sizeof(T) <= 4) constraint.


since it's a specialization of an existing method

No, this is not. A specialization would start with template<>. This case is rather an overload.
The compiler is right. The member declarations and implementations must match. If you want to tune the implementation depending on the template parameters then declare it in the class definition.
#include <utility>

class Blob {
 public:
  template <std::unsigned_integral T>
  Blob(T);
  
  template <std::unsigned_integral T>
    requires(sizeof(T) <= 4)
  Blob(T);

 private:
};

template <std::unsigned_integral T>
  requires(sizeof(T) <= 4)
Blob::Blob(T) {}

